# VBA - TextBox_Exit doesn't work properly when closing with ESC

Tags: vba, textbox, exit

I have a form with a `TextBox1` and a `CommandButton1`.

The `Cancel` property of the `CommandButton1` is `True`. So I can close the form with a key press on `Esc`.

The `TextBox1` has an Exit event, so when leaving this element will fire an event. In this event I will print the user input and some static content.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "Textbox1_Exit was fired, content was: " & TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Now I enter some content in the `TextBox1`, let's say I enter 'foo'.

If I close the form with the `CommandButton1` the output will be:

> TextBox1_Exit was fired, content was: foo

**The problem:**
If I leave the form via the `Esc` key, the output will only be:

> TextBox1_Exit was fired, content was:

So only the static part of `Debug.Print` will be printed. 
I would like to get the user input in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so this was a bit tricky - since you can't grab the `TextBox1.Value` when using `Esc` from the Userform, you can use a `Public` string variable instead which mimics the entries made into the `TextBox`. So you'll need to declare a `Public` variable, add a `TextBox_Change` event, and add a `Userform_Initialize` event to reset the string each time:

```
Public mystring As String
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If Not Len(TextBox1.Value) <= Len(mystring) + 1 Then
    mystring = mystring & Right(TextBox1.Value, 1)
Else
    If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        mystring = TextBox1.Value
    End If
End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "Textbox_Exit was fired, content was: " & mystring
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    mystring = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I don't get in which case the first condition is useful!? It was only true if I pasted some content from the clipboard, but in this case it didn't work properly. Without the one from the else condition it works perfectly!
(I have to add: Using only the `_Change` event is not an option for performance reason because it writes the change in real time and you can see a delay while writing in the used environment)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `UserForm_QueryClose` event to catch the `UserForm` exit event and call `TextBox1_Exit` one:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Debug.Print "Textbox1_Exit was fired, content was: " & TextBox1.Value
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Dim myVar As MSForms.ReturnBoolean
    Me.TextBox1_Exit myVar
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to prevent the escape key from working in the textbox.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                             ByVal Shift As Integer)
    ' Prevent escape from deleting the text in the textbox
    If KeyCode = 27 Then
        ' Disable escape
        KeyCode = 0
        ' Code for pressing the button bound to escape
        ' (closing the form) goes here.
    End If
End Sub
```

Add the method to the form module to prevent the textbox from getting cleared, when you press escape when it has focus.